# Using external cron jobs on Hostinger

Tags: wordpress, cron

I’ve used the same cron job on an external provider through every host before Hostinger. Since I moved my site there, I’ve gotten more failed job errors than the job properly executing. Because my site is new with hardly any traffic, I needed to use something other than WP-cron to execute tasks. I have it running every 10 minutes. It’s extremely important to my site for the news aggregator plugin to run on time.

I contacted Hostinger support and was told they are a host, not developers, so I was directed here. The cron job I have running on cronjob.org is this: https://progressivenewz.org/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron Is there any reason it wouldn’t be working on Hostinger, but the other hosting providers I’ve used?

I tried contacting Hostinger support. I was expecting to run as it has on the other servers.

Comment: please provide the actual cron command and your actual job. cron only executes an infinite operation at set internal. the only failure it can have is when it does not execute the given command.

Comment: At cronjob.org, I don’t have to use the actual php command, I just set the interval (every 10 minutes) and what I want it to run and it takes care of the rest. On previous hosts when I had to create the job on their server, it was something like… */10 * * * * /user/bin/public_html/wp-cron.php <dev null2. I know that is completely incorrect, but just an idea of what the hosting provider had instructed me to use. But I’ve been using the external cron service for about a year with an occasional failure if my site was down, but that’s it.